# Import list of words in to the Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long list of words that are separated by tabs. Now I have to insert them into a Word 2010 document.

Each page in the Word file is split into 4 areas and when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I can switch between areas for writing.

I assumed that when I paste my list, each word will be pasted in a distinguished area, meaning, the first word in first area, second word in second area an so on. But when I paste the list in Word, all words are pasted in the first area.

How I can solve the problem?

Comment: What are these areas that you talk about? Is it a table?

Comment: @slybloty I use `labels` in `mailings` tab for splitting pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covert the list to a table.  To do that, go to the "Insert" ribbon, selected the arrow under "Insert Table" and select "Convert Text to Table".  Format the newly created table to the same parameters as the old one.